# How to append arrays into FormData in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I've three arrays and I've to send them into formdata through Axios.the key for the array is **record[]**.but I've three arrays and I've only one key how can I send three array on the same key **record[]**
[image]
here is my code

```
const params = new FormData();
      params.append("record[]", this.props.addedOrders);
      params.append("record[]", this.props.addedCustomers);
      params.append("record[]", this.props.addedRecovery);
```

Answer (score 8):

Multiple values can be added to the same key with `FormData`.  From the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append):

> As with regular form data, you can append multiple values with the same name. For example (and being compatible with PHP's naming conventions by adding [] to the name):

Here's an example:

```js
const params = new FormData();

params.append('record[]', 1);
params.append('record[]', 2);
params.append('record[]', 3);

console.log(params.getAll('record[]'));
```

Since your question asks about appending *arrays* to `FormData`, it's worth pointing out that `FormData.append` works with strings and blobs, and other types will be converted to strings.

> If the sent value is different than String or Blob it will be automatically converted to String.

So, if you try to append an array, it will be converted to a comma-delimited list by default.  For arrays of objects that will serialize to something like `[object Object]`.  You could alternatively marshall each array to a string by using e.g. `JSON.stringify`, then convert the data back on the server side, but that's an implementation choice.

```js
const params = new FormData();

params.append('record[]', JSON.stringify([{name: 'joe'}, {name: 'bob'}]));
params.append('record[]', JSON.stringify([{name: 'rand'}, {name: 'smith'}]));

console.log(params.getAll('record[]'));
```

All that said, I would say your issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: How should the schema look in this instance? `records[]: [{ type: Object }],` doesn't work.